# Can I able connect Db without Propel or Doctrine in symfony1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4

I'm going to work in existing symfony1.4 project. In this project they didn't use a database connection.

Now I want to save and retrieve some records from database. So I need to make a db connection. Can I able connect db without using Propel or Doctrine?

How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you want to use doctrine or propel?

Answer (score 0):

Both Doctrine and Propel are wrappers above PDO

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

You can use it directly if you don't need Data Mappers and ActiveRecord.

Comment: How can i do that in symfony1.4?